# Simple regex check failing in a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a check of the following type

```
 validates :callback_handle, :format => { :with => /[_0-9a-zA-Z]+/ix }, :unless  => "callback.nil?"
```

I do not want any non 0-9, a-z A-Z characters to pass. So i set callback_handle to 
"!alksjda"  (note ! at the begining).
This test does not fail. What am I doing wrong?

I tried a few things on irb: This is what I got:

```
1.9.2-p320 :001 > a = "!askldjlad"
 => "!askldjlad" 
1.9.2-p320 :002 > a =~ /[_0-9a-zA-Z]+/ix
 => 1 
1.9.2-p320 :003 > a = "askldjlad"
 => "askldjlad" 
1.9.2-p320 :004 > a =~ /[_0-9a-zA-Z]+/ix
 => 0
```

I thought it would return false or nil on failure to find the match.

Can someone tell me what is wrong here in my understanding?

EDIT:
I figured out that  =~ will return position of a match.
So the question becomes How do I not allow something that has any other character to not match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression is still able to match, because there is at least 1 character in your string that is alpha-numeric. If you want to make sure that the entire string matches then you should define the beginning and end of the match.

Old:

```
a =~ /[_0-9a-zA-Z]+/ix
```

This is saying "match at least one of these characters somewhere in `a`.

New:

```
a =~ /\A[_0-9a-zA-Z]+\z/ix
```

This is saying "start at the beginning of the string, then match at least 1 of only these characters, followed by the end of the string" in `a`.

Comment: Nope, this is saying about a **line**, not a **string**. `"a\n!" =~ /^[_0-9a-zA-Z]+$/ix` returns `0`. You need to use `\A`+`\z` pair instead: `/\A[_0-9a-zA-Z]+\z/ix`.

Comment: Whats with the `x`-modifier?

Comment: The `x` is doing nothing in this particular case. It was copied from the original question, and I didn't worry about it, because it's also not hurting anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex just asks that your string contains 1 or more valid characters ... this should fix it :

```
 validates :callback_handle, :format => { :with => /^[_0-9a-zA-Z]+$/ix }, :unless  => "callback.nil?"
```

Comment: Check **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995210/simple-regex-check-failing-in-a-rails-model#comment19317621_13995278)** comment.